# Expecting binder but got null

Tags: flutter, dart, widgetsbinding

I'm getting this message on my log although everything works fine

```
W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!
```

Has anyone faced such issue, and how to fix it?

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Just create a new Flutter project and run it on a simulator/emulator
2. See logs, you'll get this message: "Expecting binder but got null"

**Expected behavior:**

1. There should not be such error message

**Runner Log**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62931/5G0AlEiF5bQ=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...
I/.flutter_issues(17884): Compiler allocated 4533KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
E/SurfaceSyncer(17884): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  (17884): Expecting binder but got null!
```

Comment: I used @răzvan-puiu 's answer.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

It worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding the line below in the `main()` function

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

If this doesn't work, please check that the value you pass to the `initialBinding:` in the `MaterialApp()` is not null.

Comment: I'm still getting this issue

Comment: what if I write app without using binding ?? I start to use Android studio in 2017 or 2018, at that time default project didnt use binding. I realized new project use binding in 2018 or 2019 but I always change back to old codes and write very long code with longer time... so can we just ignore the warning?

Comment: MaterialApp doesn't have initialBinding parameter

Comment: @SardorbekR Did you got how to fix this issue ?

Comment: @Rohan No, I didn't find a solution, but this message is not shown anymore

Comment: Solved.
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Comment: It's working for me. I just move that statement to first line in main() function.

Answer (score 6):

Literally

File -> Invalidate Caches -> Clear Filesystem Cache

And then rebuilding fixed it for me (React Native 0.68.2)

Answer (score 1):

The message actually doesn't affect the functionality of the app. But still you can add a line in the `main()`. Add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` in the main function

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have super.build(); in my widget for no reason. Just forgot to delete the code. So I removed the code and fixed.

```
class _VehicleAddState extends State<VehicleAdd>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<VehicleAdd> {
  double selectedMenu = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).