# Expecting binder but got null?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

E/SurfaceSyncer(30554): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  (30554): Expecting binder but got null!
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(30554): broadcast received for message
W/mple.final_push(30554): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (unsupported,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/mple.final_push(30554): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (unsupported,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/mple.final_push(30554): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/mple.final_push(30554): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(30554): broadcast received for message

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState(){
    init();
    super.initState();
  }

  init() async {
    String deviceToken = await getDeviceToken();
    print("##### PRINT DEVICE TOKEN TO USE FOR PUSH NOTIFICATION #####");
    print(deviceToken);
    print("###############################################");


  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Text('Firebase messaging'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
Future getDeviceToken() async {
    FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessage =  FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    String? deviceToken = await _firebaseMessage.getToken();
    return(deviceToken == null)? "": deviceToken;

}

}
```

Comment: Duplicated question, look at the question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73519314/expecting-binder-but-got-null